# How can i upload videos using django rest api with cloudinary

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, cloudinary

Well I'm doing a project in django rest for backend and react as front end, i want to do 2 post modals one for video and another for images, the image is fine but the video dont work, when i set filefield i get an error saying is not a valid image file, also tried to do with cloudinary where all my images are stored, i cant figure it out how to do it, tried countless times but with no avail.

The video post model:

```
class VideoPost(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
    post_categorys_filter = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, choices=post_categorys, default='normal'
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id} {self.title}'
```

The serializer:

```
class VideoPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='author.username')
    is_author = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    profile_id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='author.profile.id')
    profile_image = serializers.ReadOnlyField(
        source='author.profile.image.url')
    comments_count = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    likes_count = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    dislikes_count = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    video = serializers.FileField()

    def get_is_author(self, obj):
        request = self.context['request']
        return request.user == obj.author

    class Meta:
        model = VideoPost
        fields = [
            'id', 'author', 'is_author', 'profile_id', 'profile_image',
            'content', 'created_at', 'updated_at',
            'post_categorys_filter', 'video',
            'likes_count', 'comments_count', 'dislikes_count'
        ]
```

Comment: You can use the [Cloudinary Python SDK](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/django_image_and_video_upload#python_video_upload) and build the [CloudinaryResource object](https://github.com/cloudinary/pycloudinary/blob/6a2f5894d715e441c6b955bc62c3fc1e74e0d8ae/django_tests/test_cloudinaryField.py). Additionally, you could [refer to the following link for some examples](https://pypi.org/project/dj3-cloudinary-storage/).

Comment: You just saved my life bro not gonna lie, thank you very much